# Interface Microsoft.IDialog is not defined while running schema merge

Tags: c#, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I used the **Bot Framework Composer** to create a new bot with the **Enterprise People Bot** template.

[image: Creating a new enterprise people bot with the bot framework composer]

I opened the created solution with Visual Studio and wanted to add a custom action as described in the article [Create custom actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions).

The final step is to [merge schema files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions#merge-schema-files).

The executed powershell script gives the following output:

```
Running schema merge.
Finding component files
Parsing component .schema files
Merging component schemas
Error GetManagerDialog.dialog: Interface Microsoft.IDialog is not defined
Error GetProfileDialog.dialog: Interface Microsoft.IDialog is not defined
Error ResolveUserDialog.dialog: Interface Microsoft.IDialog is not defined


*** Could not merge components ***
Schema merge failed. Restoring previous versions.
```

After some struggeling, I skipped the part to create a custom action but just opened the automatically created solution and immediately executed the powershell script: Same error!

What does

> Interface Microsoft.IDialog is not defined

mean?

As this is pure sample code wI didn't change anything, I am wondering how this should work and why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you added reference to this library in the custom action :

> Add a reference to the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adaptive.Runtime package